# The use of the prepositions "in" and "over" in the context of time

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Tell me please if there is any difference in meaning between the following sentences.

> The team has been awarded more penalty kicks **in** the last 10 years than any other team.
>
> The team has been awarded more penalty kicks **over** the last 10 years than any other team.

Being a non-native English speaker it is undescribably hard to see any difference, so I doubt there is any.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26317/in-the-past-few-years-vs-over-the-past-few-years) this answer. To sum up, the difference can be better seen in the following sentences (also from the answer mentioned):

> I got my driver's license **in** the last year,
>
> but I learned how to drive properly **over** the past three months.

*IN* can be used mostly for discrete events, whereas *OVER* can be used for continuous cases.

Comment: This should be "[discrete](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discrete) events." The word [discreet](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discreet) means something completely different.

Comment: Oops! My bad, typo corrected.